# Difference in relative path on osx and windows

Tags: java, path, relative-path

```
    try {

        byte[] encoded = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(getClass().getResource("/files/game.json").getFile()));
        return new String(encoded);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        return "";
    }
```

This block works on osx, but when i try to run it on windows, it won't find the relative path.

Answer (score 0):

Windows uses "\" but because "\" is an escape character just use double backslash:

```
().getResource("\\files\\game.json")
```

I hope this works!

Comment: Very good answer, but it just returns the same error. 

I can maybe add, that when I feed the readAllBytes() with the direct path on
the windows computer, it does what it is supposed to.

Comment: Oh so i cant help you anymore I'm still a beginner :) Sorry

Comment: Thanks for trying though

Answer (score 0):

```
private String getGameJSONFile() throws IOException {

    byte[] bytePath = new File("src/files/game.json").getCanonicalPath().getBytes();

    String path = new String(bytePath);

    Path p = Paths.get(path);

    byte[] encoded = Files.readAllBytes(p);

    return new String(encoded);
}
```

In case someone is interested, this did the trick